# Time difference with NSDateComponents

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm building an app whereas I need to calculate the time between two NSDates.

I've subclassed `NSObject` and named it "MyObject" (simplified for the sake of this question).

It holds these two properties

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *startDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *endDate;
```

I have an array storing x number of MyObjects, which I loop through like so

```
NSTimeInterval totalInterval = 0;
for (MyObject *currentObject in _listOfItems)
{
    totalInterval += [currentObject.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentObject.startDate];
}
```

I'm using `totalInterval` to summarise the length of all the "spans" combined. I'm doing this by setting up 2 NSDates, simply for the sake of calculating the difference.

```
NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:totalInterval sinceDate:date1];
```

I'm setting up these flags:

```
unsigned int unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth;
```

And return the result as `NSDateComponent` like so:

```
return [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2  options:0];
```

My question: When I used the units above, I had the wrong result - namely **11h 20m** when the real answer is about **83h**. I learned that I was needlessly specifying the `NSCalendarUnitDay` and `NSCalendarUnitMonth` units. After reading the docs, I read that "There is no need to specify any more components than those in which you are interested" and I removed the two needlessly specified units. This gave me the right result, but how come? **Why would it report the wrong result by simply specifying more units?**

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your problem, but to get 'now', I always use [NSDate date]. Also the flags is delcared as: typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSCalendarUnit). You should not declare it as unsigned int in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would it report the wrong result by simply specifying more units?

The NSDateComponents represents all of the time between the two dates (300.000 seconds in your case), specified in a number of days (3), hours (11) and minutes (11).

Asking for just seconds will get you seconds, asking for seconds and days will give you just those. Asking just for days would give you the full number of days, so it would be 3. 
Note that NSDateComponents can either represent a date (point time), or a time interval.

This flexibility gives you the ability to create some pretty cool time-based components.

Comment: oh now I think I understand. So if I specify just the hour unit for a 2-day + 1 hour interval, it'll display 49 hours, but if I addded the day unit as well, then it'll sort it into days AND hours, so that `[components days]` would return 3, and `[components hours]` would return 1. Say I only specified the hours unit and asked for days, it would return 0 days?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. But you should not ask for units you did not specify, as the documentation tells you that the actual value is 'NSDateComponentUndefined' (which is NSIntegerMax).

Comment: So the units make it sort of like a sorting system as to how big I want the components to be? What if I gave it a week and wanted to know the total amount of both days and hours? Could you please elaborate on your last sentence? "As the documentation..."

Comment: Consider this: how many hundreds are in 3241? The answer is 32. if the question would be: 'How many tens are in 3241?' the answer is 324. Asking for thousands gives an answer of 3. Combining them, there will be some computation required: how many tens and how many thousands? Answer would be 3 thousands and (from the  remaining 241) 24 tens. This is the same as with date components, except it is with years, months, days etc. As for the last sentence  first two paragraphs of: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/

Comment: Also, NSDateComponents are kind of meaningless outside of a calendar. Year 2015, month 9 and day 15 do not represent the same moment in time in the Gregorian calendar as they do in the Buddhist Calendar or the Chinese Calendar.

Comment: Could you please explain that last comment? I'm only using the components to measure the time difference - the different calendars wouldn't impact that, would it?

Comment: Yes they would. The year 2015 in one calendar might be the year 2300 in some other calendar. I think the hebrew calendar has some months of different length compared to the gregorian calendar, and some calendars have no daylight savings time. These factors affect the what the nsdatecomponts contains after asking the calendar.

Comment: But wouldn't that display appropriately? Say 2015-2020 in the calendar I use, equals to 5 years. But year 2300-2305 is also equal to 5 years. My point is, wouldn't everything just update accordingly? Considering I'm using `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]`

Comment: In this case yes, because you use a single unit. But the number of days between 1034 and 1456 in the chinese calendar is most likely different from the number of days between the same years in the gregorian calendar. -currentCalendar returns the calendar according to the user's locale, so it might be any calendar once your app is out in the wild, and hence your computations might be off (might).

Comment: I definitely see what you mean. It's a part of the app that displays how long you've spent inside a place. Basically it's used to calculate the time from you entered a place, to when you left - so that time (for instance 7h, 30m) would change appropriately for the users. 7h to me seems correct, but in another calendar it could be 30h for the same "real" time - but the user would know that 30h to him/her is correct in their calendar.

Comment: Yes, It think you understand correctly, and I think in your app it would make sense to handle it the way you are describing!

Answer (score 3):

The calculation will always begin with the largest units that you've asked for. So if you ask for days and hours, but then only inspect hours, you will see the actual total number of hours modulo 24. This applies to any date decomposition that `NSCalendar` performs.

Comment: I think I understand. So if I specify just the hour unit for a 2-day + 1 hour interval, it'll display 49 hours, but if I addded the day unit as well, then it'll sort it into days AND hours, so that `[components days]` would return 2, and `[components hours]` would return 1. Say I only specified the hours unit and asked for days, it would return 0 days? -> making the units sort of like a sorting system as to how big I want the components to be?

Comment: No, the value of any component that you don't ask for is officially undefined; there's a special marker value, [`NSUndefinedDateComponent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSDateComponents_undefined_component_identifier) that will be in every uninitialized field of the `NSDateComponents`.